# Strange querystring in MVC4 url's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco, umbraco6

I'm building an Umbraco V6 MVC site and have a number of controllers. When you enter a URL into the address bar or click one of the navigation links like www.domain.com/candidates when the page renders the URL has changed to www.domain.com/candidates#.UqeKJvTIYUY

If you then click the same navigation link to load the page again the querystring has disappeared.

I've followed this [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FormsAuthenticationOnASPNETSitesWithTheGoogleChromeBrowserOnIOS.aspx) to ensure I'm using cookies for the account area.

Comment: I saw similar behavior when my link generation method used a wrong opject to get parameters. How do you generate the navigation links.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue in the end, it was the addThis scripts on the page.

Once these were removed, then the issue went away.

In the end they needed to have address bar tracking turned off - http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/352733-how-to-remove-hash-from-url-

You can also turn the setting off when creating Share Buttons:

[image]

Comment: There is a setting on AddThis if you sign up on the website, which allows you to turn off those crappy settings.